# Is there any function from boto3 (dynamodb) to calculate item size before insertion?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I need to know how many write units a certain object will consume before inserting it to DynamoDB.

There are some docs from AWS explaining how to estimate write units, however, I would like to check if there is some built in function in boto3 before writing my own.

```py
import boto3

some_object = { ... }

dynamo = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

# get kb size my object will consume
size = dynamo.get_size_of(some_object)

# or even how many write units
writers = dynamo.get_writers(some_object)
```

Comment: This might be helpful: https://zaccharles.github.io/dynamodb-calculator/ It has an implementation in JavaScript that could help you to translate to Python. Also be aware of the awscli's `--returned-consumed-capacity TOTAL` option with `aws dynamodb put-item`.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing *inside* boto3 for calculating the size of items you're going to write. We sometimes use the code from [this blog post](https://goshippo.com/blog/measure-real-size-any-python-object/) to check python data structures before writing them.